# Surface area of transformed sphere

Tags: geometry, transformation, surfaces, area, affine-geometry

So if I have a sphere with center C and radius R and then apply one or more affine transformations (so any combination of rotating, scaling and translating), how would I go about finding the surface area of the newly transformed sphere? Is there a general algorithm to use that would work here?

Comment: By scaling do you mean possibly into an ellipsoid? The area should be invariant under translating and rotating.

Comment: Yes, I do mean possibly into an ellipsoid, but not necessarily an ellipsoid. It could transform into a larger/smaller sphere as well for instance. It depends entirely on the scaling matrix used (a 4x4 matrix of the form {{x,0,0,0}, {0,y,0,0}, {0,0,z,0}, {0,0,0,1}}

Comment: You can calculate it by hand using the transformation formula. On the other hand you can exploit properties of the Hausdorff measure, if $T$ is your affine transformation and $S$ your starting sphere, then $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(T(S))=|T|^{n-1}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(S)$. Here $|T|$ is the modulus of the determinant of the Jacobian of $T$.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 can you explain in more detail what you mean by "using the transformation formula"? I'm also not familiar with the Hausdorff measure. This calculation is eventually going to be implemented in code, where my only starting parameters are the center point C, radius R and then transformation matrix (4x4 grid) (which I can invert, transpose, etc).

Comment: In that case I would use the formulae with the hausdorff measure. The Hausdorff is the surface Area of an object in $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, since it should be a surface and not a volume, the surface should somehow be an $n-1$ dimensional object. So for your programm, you only need to determine the initial surface area from your sphere and the determinant of the matrix and put it to the power $3$ in your case and you are done. The transformation formula is related to integrals and one can calculate also surface areas with ih (though it will probably only occur at an intermediate step)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help! I'll try this out and see how it works.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 That approach only works for transformations which distort equally in all directions. For a dilation along a single axis of the sphere, say with a scaling factor $a$, area elements near the intersection of the axis with the sphere will be distorted by a factor of $\approx 1$, whereas area elements near the "equator" will be distorted by a factor of $\approx a$.

Comment: Hmm, I feared that too, I was just checking Evans and Gariepys book and oboviously I remembered it falsely :( So sorry for that

Comment: So in that case, what would be a better approach?

Comment: You probably need to calculate integrals. To this end you need to parametrize your transformed spheres. Have you done anything like that before?

Comment: I know calculus and have used parameterization but I'm not sure how either would work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments suggested, rotations and translations leave the surface area fixed, and a dilation by a factor of $a$ changes the surface area by a factor of $a^2$, but the general case is more difficult.

Consider any affine transformation $T$. Since translations don't affect the area, we may as well postcompose our transformation with a translation and hence assume that $T$ fixes the origin. If the transformation produces an ellipsoid with semi-axis lengths $a, b, c$, we can readily set up the surface integral, but unless $a = b = c$, the resulting integral is elliptic, which means that it can't be evaluated except perhaps for some special values.

Good approximations of the surface area $S$ are, however, available: For example, the approximation
$$S \approx 4\pi\left(\frac{(bc)^p + (ca)^p + (ab)^p}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
is reasonably accurate for certain values of $p$: For $p = \frac{8}{5}$ the error is $< 1.2\%$.

If you have more information, e.g., if $a, b \gg c$, or if $a, b, c$ are all very close, then other good approximations are available.

Comment: could yo provide a source for such approximations? I haven't seen them so far.

Comment: Klamkin, "Elementary approximations to the area of n-dimensional ellipsoids." The American Mathematical Monthly, v.78 (1971)  pp.280-283. NB there is a correction given in 1976, I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: By the way, there are also exact formulas (involving inverse hyperbolic functions) for the special cases where two of $a, b, c$ are equal.

Comment: How would I go about calculating a,b,c though if my original sphere only has a radius r?

Comment: If your transformation matrix is as in your earlier comment, i.e., a diagonal matrix of the form $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, 1)$, then the transformation dilates by a factor $\alpha$ in the $x$ direction, etc., and so the transformed ellipse has semi-axes $\alpha r, \beta r, \gamma r$.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help.